# How to XOR two byte arrays of different length

Tags: java, arrays, byte, xor

I have two byte[ ] variables of different length which I would use to XOR to give me the third variable. Let's call them **b1** and **b2**, and the third variable **b3**.

Using this third variable, I can:

1. **b3** XOR **b2** to give me **b1**.
2. **b3** XOR **b1** to give me **b2**.

However, I have a problem with getting back the values of **b1** and **b2** as they are not of the same length.

```
public static byte[] xor(byte[] b1, byte[] b2) {
    byte[] oneAndTwo = new byte[Math.min(b1.length, b2.length)];
    for (int i = 0; i < oneAndTwo.length; i++) {
        oneAndTwo[i] = (byte) (((int) b1[i]) ^ ((int) b2[i]));
    }
    return oneAndTwo;
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    byte[] b1 = "Hi".getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] b2 = "Hello".getBytes("UTF-8");
    byte[] b3 = XORTest.xor(b1, b2);

    byte[] mb1 = XORTest.xor(b2, b3);
    byte[] mb2 = XORTest.xor(b1, b3);

    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(b1, mb1));   //prints true
    System.out.println(new String(mb1, "UTF-8")); //prints "Hi"

    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(b2, mb2));   //prints false
    System.out.println(new String(mb2, "UTF-8")); //prints "He"
}
```

So I would like to know if there's a way to perform XOR on two byte[ ] of different length.

Comment: Instead of making the return byte[] the minimum length you could make it the maximum length instead. Or you could make it the length of the first argument.

Comment: I don't think this is possible without passing additional information: if your `xor` method returns b3 as the minimum length, you loose information from the longer byte array. If the xor method returns the maximum length then you wont know the length of the smaller array

Comment: @ThomasKläger I thought knowing the length might be a problem, unless you assume trailing 0s can be truncated.

Comment: @PeterLawrey assuming trailing 0s can be truncated is one possible way to transport this extra information

Answer (score 1):

One solution is to take the maximum length so no information is lost, but assume that trailing 0 bytes should be truncated.

```
public static byte[] xor(byte[] b1, byte[] b2) {
    byte[] oneAndTwo = new byte[Math.max(b1.length, b2.length)];
    for (int i = 0; i < b1.length && i < b2.length; i++)
        oneAndTwo[i] = (byte) (b1[i] ^ b2[i]);
    for (int i = b2.length; i < b1.length; i++)
        oneAndTwo[i] = b1[i];
    for (int i = b1.length; i < b2.length; i++)
        oneAndTwo[i] = b2[i];
    int length = oneAndTwo.length;
    while (length > 0 && oneAndTwo[length - 1] == 0)
        length--;
    if (length < oneAndTwo.length)
        return Arrays.copyOf(oneAndTwo, length);
    return oneAndTwo;
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] b1 = "Hi".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] b2 = "Hello".getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
    byte[] b3 = xor(b1, b2);

    byte[] mb1 = xor(b2, b3);
    byte[] mb2 = xor(b1, b3);

    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(b1, mb1));  
    System.out.println(new String(mb1, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

    System.out.println(Arrays.equals(b2, mb2));   
    System.out.println(new String(mb2, StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
}
```

prints

```
true
Hi
true
Hello
```